# db2 query slow from applications but so fast on db server

Tags: aix, db2-luw

I run a query from my applications. It may cost 3 or 4 minutes. Then, I checked the sql from logs and run it directly on the db server(DB2,9.7).It was so fast, less than 1 seconds.

It's prd environment and I cannot get the entire environments. As i know, the programming-language is java, and Mybatis they use. The sql limits fetching first 1000 rows and it started to be slow from last week, after we build an index to optimize another query.

We click the other interface buttons and we get results so fast(less then 1 seconds after clicking button).So I think the network is ok.

I am sure that two sqls are the same.

Comment: Learn how to ask a good question. Please edit your question, to add facts, details of the configuration, client side configuration, result-set size (#number of rows, #average width of a row in the result-set), which programming-language submits the SQL and how the result-set is retrieved. Is the symptom the same for *every* query, or just some queries, or just one single query? What is the network latency between client and server etc?  Also specify how you calculate the elapsed time.  There's no information in your question that could lead to any meaningful answer.

Comment: Are both queries really the same? Don't you compare parameterized query from your application with semantically the same query you run manually, but with constants instead of parameter markers?

Comment: Today, I directly copy the sql from the logs and run manually again. There is no differences between the two sqls.  And, I get the output of db2expln. We compare the both sqls' plan. It is the same. So wierd.